# using javascript hide ul on button click, where value is inserted to mysql on button click also

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hohow to hide a ul on button click in php
 ?>

```
                            <li style='width:115px;margin-left:7px;word-wrap:break-word;'><?php echo  $row['title'];?></li>
                            <li style='width:90px;margin-left:7px;word-wrap:break-word;'><?php echo  $row['status'];?></li>                    
                            <li style='width:80px;margin-left:7px;word-wrap:break-word;'><?php echo  $row['added_date'];?></li>
                            <li style="width:40px;text-align:left;margin-left:5px;"><a href="<?php echo $url;?>?p=<?php echo $currentPage;?>&show=1&guest_id=<?php echo $guestId;?>&enquiry_id=<?php echo $enquiry_id;?>&pid=<?php echo $proposalId;?>"  style="text-decoration:none;" >Edit</a></li> 
                        <li style="width:70px;text-align:left;"><a id="link" name="link" href="addguestinformation.php?enq=<?php echo $row['enq_id'];?>&pid=<?php echo $proposalId; ?>"  style="text-decoration:none;" >Booking</a></li> 
                            <!--<li style="width:70px;text-align:left;"><button id="bookingconfirm" name="bookingconfirm" class="button" type="button" onclick="bookingForm(<?php //echo $row['enq_id']?>);">Booking</button>-->


                          </ul>
```

Comment: you can't control button click using php, use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery you can hide Element UL

```
    $('ul').on('click',function(){
            this.fadeout('slow');//when you click on Ul this will hide Ul
    });
```

```
        to hide UL with attribute Id use
```

```
     $('#hide').on('click',function(){
            this.fadeOut('slow');

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying punk ..<ul id="hide" name="hide" style="text-align:left;width:450px;"  >here hide is the ul id. then, how can i hide ?

Comment: please explain your answer not just dumping the code. also, you might want to mention that is a `jquery` code which he may not be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

well with php alone you are not really able to do this without reloading the page and now thats just not so user friendly but there is [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) which is a javascript library that can do just that for you

```
    //Gets the referance of the DOM Object by using the ID 
    $('#hideButton').click(function(e){

    //prevents the default action of the button
        e.preventDefault();

    //Hides the list
        $('#foo').fadeOut('slow', function(b){
           //What to do once the list has faded out
            alert('hidden');
        });
    });
```

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yq69X/1/) for a working JSfiddle

Comment: @sam did any of this help you ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, here the <ul> given is in one page and the button click event is on another page,(so when am clicking on the button the event goes to js and then it should hide the <ul> in that page

Comment: @sam you are being vague please post your code properly of what you have tried so far so that we can get a proper idea of what you want..